# Powershell Script for getting username and lastlogon/off from text file

Tags: powershell

```
$Inventory = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\computer list.txt" 
foreach ($Computer in $Inventory) {
    (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object name -Match explorer).getowner().user
}
```

I'm trying to run a script that will get me the username and timestamp of lastlogon through a list of computer names in a text file associated with AD.

I can manage to get the names but I run into null-valued errors as it goes through the list and takes longer than expected to finish.

How would I go about fixing that and adding a timestamp for users who last logged on/off?

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be to parse through event logs to find their log on log off times

this script looks like it fits the bill

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-user-logon-duration-667b8c48

you could then use it like this

```
$Inventory = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\computerlist.txt'
ForEach ($Computer in $Inventory) {
    Get-OSCUserLogonDuration -ComputerName $Computer -IncludeRemoteInteractive - 
    Verbose | FT -AutoSize
}
```